# How to make SSL connection using Bouncy Castle?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, bouncycastle, stdstring

Can you please help me with starter Java code that just make SSL connection with an HTTPS server on port 443 (SSL) & returns to me a Certificate Object so I can access certificate properties such as expiration date, public key length, etc. I have done something similar to this using java built in libraries. Now, I  reached some restrictions. I want to try using BC. But need help at the beginning.

Comment: You reached what restrictions?

Comment: @EJP In Java libraries, I was unable to edit the list of supported cipher suites. I want to make custom list of specific cipher suites for testing purposes. some of htese ciphers are not in the list of supported cipher suites. Do you think I BC can help me in this?

Comment: Only if it supports them. I suggest you research that first.

Comment: @EJP Bouncy Castle supports the ciphers I want. I checked that. But How to edit the Cipher suite list in Java?? I searched a lot for very long time not being able to find helpful answer.